# File upload speeds way below what they should be

Tags: networking, server, 18.04, apache2, transfer

I'm currently running a LAMP server on Ubuntu 18.04. The website I'm hosting is for file transfers. My upload speed through the site is around 5-7kb MAX. Using an SFTP program I get 30KB MAX speeds whether it's local network or not. To ensure it was the server and not my code I moved everything to another host and I got regular speeds. When downloading from the server however, I get alright speeds 2Mbps on a 20Mb file.

Testing the servers internet speed it still gets 40Mbps up and 10Mbps down.
Any clue what could be causing the slow transfer speeds or what I could do to test it? I'm very new to Ubuntu and can't really find any information to help me find this particular issue.

Comment: one shot in the blue: perhaps your server runs out of randomness? check `cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail` https://serverfault.com/questions/172337/explain-in-plain-english-about-entropy-available In case this is true you should have a look at `haveged` to counter this.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be it. Went ahead and installed haveget and set it up. No change in speeds though.